How can I increase the "depth" of my workbench render?
I try to recreate MC Escher's "Cubic Division of Space" in Blender. I made a model using geometry nodes. Now I want to render a short animation of the camera moving through the model using the workbench engine. However the render does not show the full depth of my model.
I want the render to look like this:

But it looks like this:

Is there any way to fix this problem?

I think this is not related to the workbench render but the camera clip end (which defaults to 100m for initial camera, 1000m for others)

Thank you very much! Your comment helped me a lot. I am new to Blender and didn't know about camera clipping.
